# Using react router inside redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, connected-react-router

If we wanted to change route programatically inside redux, we used to use `react-router-redux` npm package. However it was archived by its author. Now the recommended solution is `connected-react-router`:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/connected-react-router

But as the docs say in this package, it should be used INSTEAD of `react-router` to make it work.

Normally I was using `react-router-dom`:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

<BrowserRouter>
   <Route path='/' />
   <Route path='/hey' />
</BrowserRouter>
```

But as the docs say, I have to replace `react-router v4/v5` with `ConnectedRouter` from package:

```
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';

<ConnectedRouter history={history}>
   <Route path={'/'} />
   <Route path={'/foo'} />
</ConnectedRouter>
```

But this situation causes problem with `Link` from `react-router-dom`. `Link` has to be placed inside `BrowserRouter`, but I CANT USE IT because there's no `BrowserRouter` because AS THE DOCS ARE SAYIN - **"Remember to delete any usage of BrowserRouter or NativeRouter as leaving this in will cause problems synchronising the state."**

Problem is that `ConnectedRouter` is a connected version of `react-router`, not `react-router-dom`, so theres nothing like `Link` or `NavLink` in it.

There must be some way, if not I believe this package wouldnt have 3k stars on github...

#### Question: How to use `Link` inside `ConnectedRouter`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**I recommend you to stick to to react-router-dom only.**

There is no need for connecting it to redux anymore. In the past there could be a reason because it was hard to read the current pathname or search param, since only main page components were receiveing these as location. But right now you can read from anywhere thanks to withRouter.

Also you can use history to push routes. This was also a headache in the past.

Comment: Unfortunately im not able to use hoc in e.g. redux-saga, I will have to pass it down instead.

Comment: I think you better pass it to redux-saga. Or you could just read window.location.pathname..